# How to configure Delete in Outlook to save items to folder other than Deleted Items

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Let's say that you don't want to use the Deleted Items folder in Outlook. Instead when you delete a message, you want it to go to a folder other than Deleted Items (for example, a folder called "Unneeded". Is there a way to configure Outlook to do that? Also assume that you are using Exchange and Auto Archive is disabled.

Comment: Wich Outlook do you use? 2010?

Comment: 2010 (sorry I thought I had included that)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it will not be configurable.

See if this works for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854770/outlook-2007-intercepting-a-mail-delete-command/11998947#11998947